# can I download the litecoin blockchain from the webbrowser?

Tags: wallet, litecoin

even with 13 active connections, the blockchain seems to be downloading at an unreasonably slow rate. considering the large amount of traffic, the sooner the sync the better as it's possible that it will grow by a lot while I'm still downloading. 
my provider seems to slow the internet whenever something peer-to-peer is happening(certain video games,etc) so the fact that it's such a large file downloaded over P2P is also a  concern.

I want to be able to simply store coins I get today and in the future, not look at all the non-existent past ones. while multibit does this for bitcoin, I can't find a similar app for Litecoins.